# Sum Case When query

Tags: sql-server

This is a general SQL question

I have this table (simplified), credits are positive, debits are negative:

```
Account Amount  Type
--------------------
john    25      credit  
john    45      debit  
john    5       debit  
john    15      credit  
mike    15      credit
```

I want to have a result that looks like this, using a single query using `Case When`:

```
Account  Total
--------------------
john     -10      
mike     15
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` construct to distinguish between debit and credit entries.

```
SELECT   account, SUM (amount * CASE type WHEN 'credit' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Thanks Murenik, I understand the logic here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following if it makes more sense to you:

```
SELECT a.Account, b.Credits - a.Debits AS Total FROM
    (SELECT Account, SUM(Amount) AS Debits
        FROM YourTable GROUP BY Account HAVING Type = 'debit'
    ) AS a
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Account, SUM(Amount) AS Credits
        FROM YourTable GROUP BY Account HAVING Type = 'credit'
    ) AS b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(amount * case when type = 'debit' then -1 else 1 end)
```